# How can I use youtube start attribute with autoplay in iframe?

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I would like to embed a video with autoplay and from a specifick time.
I tryed this way:

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?start=75?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

But this not realy working, only one "?"  can work, not two, if I use one, the video working, but I need all.

Is that possible embed video in iframe with this two attribute?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is:
You need to replace question mark for: "&"
So the correct code is:

```html
 <iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?start=75&autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
try like this...
https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?autoplay=1
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embe/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
</iframe>

you have to remove
start=75. try this..
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: But I needed start 75, like I said in the question

Comment: may i know why you need start 75

Comment: Sorry..i didn't understand your answer...but now i can understand..yes ? replace this by &

Comment: Maybe this link help for you why need me both of them:
http://jsbin.com/vawohudomi/edit?html,output
I use lightbbox for users can view youtube links, and when usersclick for links I don't whant click again for the video, becouse this lame solution